# CsvHelper : Intialize a map member

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csvhelper

Imagine a collection of EF dbSet like this :

```
public class Employee {
  ...
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public List<Badge> Badge { get; set; } 
}

public class Badge {
  public long CSN { get; set; }
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

This models are used in my SGBB and I want to use it to import data from a CSV file. But this file has a small difference. It give only one badge like this :

```
FIRSTNAME;CSN;TYPE
Jerome;12345;1
```

I have used a CollectionGenericConverter, to initialize the List with a new record.

```
Map(m => m.Firstname).Name("Firstname");
Map(m => m.Badges).Name("CSN").TypeConverter<BadgeConverter>();

...

public class BadgeConverter : CollectionGenericConverter {
   public override object ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData) {
       return new List<Badge> {
           new Badge {
               CSN = Convert.ToInt16(text)
           }
       };
   }
}
```

I have just a problem with the second value, using a second converter reset the list of badges :

```
 Map(m => m.Badges).Name("Type").TypeConverter<AnotherOneBadgeConverter>();
```

And set directly the first item not work :

```
 Map(m => m.Badges[0].Type).Name("Type");
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("FIRSTNAME;CSN;TYPE");
            writer.WriteLine("Jerome;12345;1");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EmployeeMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Employee>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Badge> Badge { get; set; }
}

public class Badge
{
    public long CSN { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeMap: ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FIRSTNAME");
        Map(m => m.Badge).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {
            var list = new List<Badge>
            {
                new Badge { CSN = row.GetField<long>("CSN"), Type = row.GetField<int>("TYPE") },
            };
            return list;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks David